# React - How to test DOM manipulation (e.g. using document)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a utility function that finds the first input element on the page and puts it in focus.

```
export const focusOnFirstInputElement = () => {
    const wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('.main-wrapper')

    if (wrapper && wrapper.length > 0) {
        const inputElements = wrapper.querySelectorAll('input')
        
        if (inputElements && inputElements.length > 0) {
            inputElements[0].focus()
        }
    }
}
```

I use it like this in my React component:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        focusOnFirstInputElement()
    })

    return (
        <div></div>
    )
}
```

How do I take unit test this utility function (either using React Testing Library or jest)? I'm not testing the rendering of something in the DOM but that the DOM contains some elements and that a focus happens on it.

```
describe('focusOnFirstInputElement', () => {
    it('focuses on first input element in the DOM', () => {

        // Mock some kind of document? This is definitely not how you do it
        // but the gist of what I'd like to do: mock out a fake DOM against which to run  
        // the utility function.
        const mockDocument = "
            <main class='main-wrapper'>
                <input id='input1' />
                <input id='input2' />
                <input id='input3' />
            </main>"

        focusOnFirstInputElement();

        // Check that the input1 element is focused
        expect(document.activeElement === document.getElementById('input1')).toBe(true)
    })
})
```

Comment: Does the DOM rendered by `MyComponent` or outside of it?

Comment: I'd say it depends a bit on what you actually want to test. E.g. the Component: [Render a test react-component](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html#rendering); The whole page: add it to the page; The utility function (unit-test): Mock `document` (and maybe also consider separating the DOM method `getElementsByClassName` from your utility function).